# Generic Class with Static Nested Class of the Same Type

Tags: java, generics, nested-class

I am trying to write a generic configuration loader which supports loading into any target data structure by means of using a helper object supplied by the caller.  The helper is used to divorce the loader from any knowledge of the data structure, with methods to pre-process member values, create substructures and add/remove members from the structures.

Given the class and variable declaration:

```
public class ConfigLoader<T extends Object>
...
private final Class<T>                  stcClass;
```

and the static nested interface:

```
static public interface Helper<T>
{
public Object configValue(String qulfld                , String loc);
public Object configValue(String qulfld, T          val, String loc);
public Object configValue(String qulfld, String     val, String loc);
public Object configValue(String qulfld, Boolean    val, String loc);
public Object configValue(String qulfld, Number     val, String loc);

public T      crtObject();
public void   addMember(T tgt, String fld, Object val);
public void   rmvMember(T tgt, String fld);
}
```

and the base constructor:

```
private ConfigLoader(JsonParser psr, Helper<T> hlp, DataStruct vld) {
    super();

    parser      =psr;
    helper      =hlp;
    stcClass    =helper.crtObject().getClass(); // <== error here
    validation  =vld;
    errors      =new ArrayList<Fail>();
    }
```

I am getting a compiler error in the constructor line indicated:

```
ConfigLoader.java:79: error: incompatible types
    stcClass    =helper.crtObject().getClass();
                                            ^
  required: Class<T>
  found:    Class<CAP#1>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class ConfigLoader
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
1 error
```

The intent is to create one dummy structure up front from which to extract the `Class<T>` object, which is then used in some other code to validate the structure type and then to invoke the helper visitor method with the `T` argument using `helper.configValue(qulnam,stcClass.cast(val),loc.toString())`.

What I can't figure out is why the compiler can't validate that the return of the helper's `crtObject` method is guaranteed to be in fact a `T` object since the helper passed to the constructor is itself a `Helper<T>`.

The only alternative I am seeing is to pass in a `Class<T>` as a constructor argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *The only alternative I am seeing is to pass in a `Class<T>` as a constructor argument.* Yes, there's no other way to know the class type due to type erasure. Also, using `<T extends Object>` is the same as `<T>`.

Comment: You should probably have the target class object into your helper class and use it to instantiate. You could do this using a static factory method, for instance: `public static <T> Helper forClass(Class<? extends T>) { etc(); }`

Comment: @fge that's stated in the last part of the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza oops, didn't see... However, the "static factory method" hint still stands ;)

Comment: If you see OP's user history, you will check that he has some exp with Java and looks that this question is just about the design.

Comment: @Arun: Added that to the question, but it's `private final Class<T> stcType;`

Comment: @Luiggi: It's equal parts clean design and understanding why this doesn't work.  Given that the helper is of type `<T>` and that getClass returns a `Class<T>`, it follows to me that `Helper.crtObject().getClass()` returns a `Class<T>`, not a class of an unknown capture.

Comment: PS: I understand that the enclosing class' `T` and the interfaces `T` are separate, but the `Helper` passed to the enclosing class is of type `T` in it's scope, so the two types should agree.

Comment: Maybe `stcType` should be `Class<? extends T> stcType`

Comment: The [`Object.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method doesn't return `Class<T>`, it returns `Class<? extends Object>`. If we have `T obj` the type erasure of `T` be `Object`, `obj.getClass()` would return `<? extends Object>`, the reason for such a return type is because obj could actually refer to an instance of any subclass of `T` (`Object`). So `Class<T> c = obj.getClass();` doesn't work, since `obj.getClass()` is happens at runtime and compiler can't guarantee that it will always return `Class<T>`, not `Class<SomeSubClassOfT>`.

Comment: @Bhesh: But it's not any old object, it's an object which the compiler *knows* and can *prove* is of type `T`, since it came from a `Helper<T>` object passed in to the constructor.  I will try the declaration of `<? extends T>` as others have suggested.

Comment: It's type is `T`, whose type-erasure is `Object`. And the way the the method `Object.getClass()` declared it will always return `Class<? extends Type_Erasure_Of_Type_Argument_In_Parameterized_Type>`.

Comment: @Bhesh: It finally clicked - thanks for your patience.  My basic mistake was thinking `getClass` returned `<T>` rather than `<?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the type of `stctype` as `<? extends T>`.

```
private final Class<? extends T> stcType;
```

This will ensure that the `stctype` is able to handle `T` or any subclass of `T`.

In order to get rid of the compiler error, you can now safely cast the `helper.crtObject().getClass();` to `Class<? extends T>` as follows:

```
stcClass = (Class<? extends T>) helper.crtObject().getClass();
```

Comment: What I decided to do was add a method to the helper to return the class, instead of passing it in.  That seemed cleanest and kept the type-specific code all together.